# Preimage of a certain function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm having some troubles in writting in a nice form the preimage of the function that parametrize the circunference $\mathbb S^1$:

$$\begin{array}{lrc} 
          f\ \colon &\mathbb R \longrightarrow& \mathbb S^1 \\ 
          &t \longmapsto& (\cos(\pi t), \sin (\pi t))
         \end{array}$$
My reasoning was this:

If $(x,y)\in \mathbb S^1$ with $f(t)=(x,y)\iff \begin{cases}x=\cos(\pi t)\\ y=\sin (\pi t)\end{cases}\Longrightarrow \dfrac{y}{x}=\tan(\pi t)\Longrightarrow \pi t=\arctan\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)+k\pi,\ k\in \mathbb Z\Longrightarrow$

$\Longrightarrow t\in f^{-1}((x,y))=\left \{\arctan\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)+k\mid k\in \mathbb Z\right \}$.

But this doesn't work because we miss the sign of the points, because $f^{-1}((x,y))=f^{-1}((-x,-y)).$

Comment: The answer is $\frac 1 {\pi} \arctan (\frac y x)+2k: k \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: I have notice that it would be  problem if $x=0$ in my solution, and in yours too

Comment: For $x=0$ it is $t=2n+\frac 12$ if $y=1$ and $t=(2n+1)+\frac 1  2 $ if $y=-1$.

Comment: @GoRza the singularity is removable though so remove it.

Comment: Notice the "$\implies$"  that are not "$\iff$". This is similar to $x-1=0\implies x^2-1=0\implies x\in\{-1,1\}$ .... HINT: For each $n\in\Bbb Z$ there is exactly one $t'\in [2n\pi,(2n+2)\pi)$ such that $(\cos t',\sin t')=(\cos t,\sin t).$